# Why is BrowserWindow.setSize / setBounds / setContentBounds / setMaximumSize / setContentSize not working correctly in electron app?

Tags: electron

In code:

```
 let win: BrowserWindow;
    ....
    win.setSize(width, height);
    win.setPosition(x, y, false);
    win.setBounds({
          height
          width
          x,
          y,
        });
```

Data:

```
{ x: 1578, y: 915, width: 342, height: 125 }
```

But in result:
[image]

but why does such a result come out as in the picture? The width for some reason became 410! I ask 342, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use .setSize or .setPosition, .setBounds sets the position and size...

.setBounds argument (looks like you have some syntax errors) is a rectangle whose parameter values are in the order x, y, width, height. Unless you explicitly specify parameter names and values.

You can set the window position using .setBounds:

```
    win.setBounds({
          x: 1578,
          y: 915,
          width: 342,
          height: 125
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in electron side, which when the screen resolution is an odd number like 125% it adjusts pixels randomly. check the link
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27651